# There something wrong with my trophy

Tags: modeling, export

[image]

I use UV Sphere to make thìs trophy, and I choose the smooth, in Blender, it is quite good and smooth.

But when I export to .model file, and import to the Pes 2017 game, it shows the edges.

Answer (score 1):

So there could be few reasons for that. The first that the game engine does not smooth shade the same way as blender viewport engine. You can try of course making it high poly, or at least minimalizing the angles between faces. Also I would check if material/texture is applied correctly and faces are not overlapping - that can cause the artefacts at angles as well.